# What does "anything" mean here?

Tags: grammar

"These are the angry ones who would demand that others bring what love they have into madness to take responsibility for the mess that has been made, 
to attempt to restore order to chaos, (anything) so that the angry ones feel less alone with what their anger shows them."

Is "anything" apposition with "chaos" in this sentence?

Thank you for the answers as always!

Comment: Did you write the sentence? If not, could you link the article where it appears? I'm asking this because it's a complex sentence to decipher. Does "*anything*" appear inside braces as you've written? Or have you enclosed it for emphasis?

Comment: Yes, it`s the one in the braces. I was asked this question by the other student, and I can`t find the source material. Sorry. If any what kind of an nuance does the word sound to have here?

Comment: Seriously I've no clue! I'm wondering what "anything" is doing there.

Comment: Really? then it must have been a false question. It`s totally possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Anything..." is one of the things the angry ones want the others to do. It's not in apposition with "chaos".

The angry ones want the 'others' to "bring what love they have into the madness" in order to do three things:

1. take responsibility for the mess that has been made
2. attempt to restore order to chaos
3. *anything* [to make] the angry ones feel less alone with what their anger shows them

The third point is a generalization of the first two.